# In a parabola can I calculate the chord length by only knowing the arc length of the section?

Tags: geometry

If in a parabola we are given only the arc length , is there any method by which we can calculate the chord length?

Comment: What do you think about this problem? Any promising leads, etc.?

Comment: Think about this: the arc length is given by $r\angle \theta$ and the area of a triangle is equal to $\frac 12ab \sin \theta$. Do you think there is a relationship between these two?

Comment: I assume you know the radius. Then you know the central angle. Draw a picture and use a little trigonometry. (Without trigonometry you can only answer some very special cases.)

Comment: But if you don't know the radius, then the answer is, of course not.

Comment: No.  Suppose that you know that the arc length is $2\pi$.  If the circle has radius $1$, then the chord length is zero; but if the circle has radius $2$, then the chord is a diameter of length 4.  As Gerry Myerson points out, you need some other piece of information, such as the radius.

Comment: You changed it from "circle" to "parabola"! It looks like you don't even know what question you want to ask, and also you've made nonsense out of the comments and answer that have been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the arc length by the circumference which will give the value of angle subtended in radians.Now join the two radii to the end points of the arc.Now you can find the chord length by doing the solution of this triangle.(adjust to take minor arc)